# Find the rate of convergence?

Tags: analysis, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

Given is the iteration $x_{k+1}=\frac{1}{11}(1-\cos(x_{k}))$ with $x_{0}\in (-\frac{\pi }{2},\frac{\pi }{2})$ without $0$. Check if the sequence converges to $x^{*}=0$ and find its convergence rate.

Well, i am stuck in this obviously very easy first part of the problem. Wolfram Alpha shows that $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1}{11}(1-\cos(x))=0$, so the sequence converges to the given $x^{*}=0$. Can anyone give me a hint how to solve this limit, please?

Second, the convergence rate. I know the definitions of sublinear convergence, superlinear convergence etc. 
I need to calculate the $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{\left \| x_{k+1} -x^{*}\right \|}{\left \| x_{k}-x^{*} \right \|}$, so $lim _{x\rightarrow \infty } \frac{\left | \frac{1}{11}(1-\cos(x)) \right |}{\left | x \right |}=lim_{x\rightarrow \infty }\frac{1-\cos(x)}{11x}= 0$. So, the sequnce converges superlinearly. Is the idea correct at all? Can anybody help me with this problem, please?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not so sure how you managed to obtain that $\lim_{x→∞} (1-\cos(x))/11 = 0$ because this limit doesn't exist. The graph is forever waving about between $1/11$ and $0$:
[image: its the curvy line]

But more importantly, the behaviour of this function at infinity is not really relevant when we are talking about starting with $|x_0| < \pi/2$ and trying to get a null sequence.

Hint: you can try showing that $1-\frac{x^2}{2} < \cos x $ and use this to get a bound on $|x_k|$ which should tend to $0$ irrespective of the starting point $x_0 ∈ (-π/2,π/2)\setminus \{0\}$.

This will also give you a bound up to a constant on the convergence rate, so if a reasonable Big-O is all you want, you're done at this point. If you want to show 
that there is a quadratic lower bound as well, try scaling $p(x):=-(x-π/2)(x+π/2)$ to have the same maximum height in $(-\pi/2 , \pi/2)$ as $\cos(x)$ and use this to bound $cos(x)$ from above now.